# Buildozer выдает ошибку (отсутствие файла pyconfig.h)

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Подскажите пожалуйста, чего не хватает и в какой папке?

Звучит банально, но все же....))

Вроде бы все зависимости что нужно (и не нужно) влепил.

Система ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64 на VirtualBox,

Kivy 1.11.1

Пересмотрел видео Олега Молчанова на YouTube ("Уроки Kivy #1: Установка kivy и сборка APK) и из него все по шагово сделал. Во время процесса : [INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1 , выдает следующее:

```
/home/tramplin30/Загрузки/projects/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-
v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/Python.h:8:10: fatal error: 
      **'pyconfig.h' file not found**
#include "pyconfig.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [/home/tramplin30/Загрузки/projects/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/main/start.o] Error 1


  STDERR:
```

Заранее спасибо!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0');
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '320');
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '240');

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        s = Scatter()
        fl = FloatLayout(size = (190, 120))
        s.add_widget(fl)
        fl.add_widget(Button(text = "Кнопка!",
                            font_size = 20,
                            on_press = self.btn_press,
                            background_color = [.32,.65,0,1],
                            background_normal = "",
                            size_hint = (.5, .25),
                            pos = (80,100)))
        return s

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        print ("Кнопка нажата")
        instance.text = "Я нажата"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1031 Цитата: `python.h is a part of python-dev versions so.. You could use venv with buildozer but you need to have python-dev inside it. You can create it with: virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6-dev <path>`